# The main clause in future tense, the sub clause in present tense

Tags: future-tense

> On Monday, Chicago **will** make history when Lori Lightfoot **becomes** the
>   city’s first black female mayor.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the use case here is similar to that of **Type 1 Conditional** tense.

> The type 1 conditional is used to refer to the present or future where the situation is real. The type 1 conditional refers to a possible condition and its probable result. In these sentences the if clause is in the simple present, and the main clause is in the simple future.

In Type 1 Conditional, the sentence would somewhat be like this:

> On Monday, Chicago will make history if Lori Lightfoot becomes the city’s first black female mayor.

The difference is your example uses `when` instead of `if`.

> We use if to introduce a possible condition. We use when to refer to the time of a future situation or condition that we are certain of.

It adds more emphasis on the certainty of the event happening (**make history**) as well as refering to the time (**Monday**).